# How to use PHP function parameter inside array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, function

I am trying to declare a function parameter inside my array, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I've trimmed it down for simplicity purposes, and I have something like:

```
function taken_value($value, $table, $row, $desc) {
    $value = trim($value); 
    $response = array();

    if (!$value) { 
        $response = array(
            'ok' => false, 
            'msg' => "This can not be blank."
        );
    } else if (mysql_num_rows(
                   mysql_query(
                       "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $row = '$value'"))) {
        $response = array(
            'ok' => false,
            'msg' => $desc." is already taken."
        );  
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'ok' => true, 
            'msg' => ""
        ); 
    }
    echo json_encode($response); 
}
```

Notice the function parameter `$desc` trying to be used in the array here:

```
'msg' => $desc." is already taken.");
```

The whole function works fine EXCEPT when I try to add the `$desc` to the array results.

How could this be done?

Comment: It should work. Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, I just don't get any output from the function. It would be hard to say if I had an error because this can only display on POST from some ajax stuff.

Comment: That particular part of your code appears to work: http://codepad.org/SBmOhhX1 Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: As Radu said, it should work, have you made sure, that $desc is set at all?

Comment: How do you know your query is working? If it's not, it will automatically call the next, blank return value. This is not a great way to do this.

Comment: Yes but my form does not submit if "ok" is false, so I don't need the 'msg' value. On my form, the only thing 'msg' is used for is to display an error. The form works fine without using $desc but as soon as I use it, the whole thing stops working. And, yes I did include $desc as POST value that gets sent to this page.

Comment: Syntax-wise, there isn't anything wrong with the part you've pointed out. Have you used a console to inspect the response? If it's blank, that sounds like a syntax error which (probably) exists somewhere else in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Thanks for looking over the code. You all are right, it was a user error (Thanks Jared for making me go back through everything).

This function is the second to get triggered on the page. I forgot to declare the parameter in the first function. I was going to post the code here but I can't answer my own question for 8 hours... go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an open resource handle to your database? You are not passing one to the query function.